# Making a fractal graph using a 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Found this exercise online to practice Python3, and I am almost done, but it doesn't give the result advertised.

Basically, it is supposed to make many points move randomly then stick together from the bottom of the graph to make a fractal that looks like this:

[image: what the final result should look like]

The code makes 5000 points and make them walk randomly in the north, south, west or east direction on a limited graph. The top of the code until the `if` condition works. after moving, it makes a test if there is any infected `points(bool value True in grilleFixe)` around their position. if so, they stop moving, turning their position in `grilleFixe` from `False` to `True`, making them infected too.

I think the problem is in the `if` condition. It seems like it makes every points infected.

```
N=256 
M=5000 
nIterMax=100000 
x=np.random.random_integers(1,N,M) 
y=np.random.random_integers(1,N,M) 

statusMobile=np.ones(M,dtype='bool') 
grilleFixe=np.zeros([N+2,N+2],dtype='bool') 
grilleFixe[:,0]=True 

nFixe=0 
iter=0 

while (nFixe<M) and (iter<nIterMax):
    m,=np.where(statusMobile) 

    d=random.sample([[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]],  1)
    pas=d[0]

    x[m]=np.clip(x[m]+pas[0],1,N) 
    y[m]=np.clip(y[m]+pas[1],1,N) 

    closefix= grilleFixe[x[m]-1,y[m]-1]
    closefix+=grilleFixe[x[m] ,y[m]-1]
    closefix+=grilleFixe[x[m]+1,y[m]-1]
    closefix+=grilleFixe[x[m]+1,y[m] ]
    closefix+=grilleFixe[x[m]+1,y[m]+1]
    closefix+=grilleFixe[x[m] ,y[m]+1]
    closefix+=grilleFixe[x[m]-1,y[m]+1]
    closefix+=grilleFixe[x[m]-1,y[m] ]

    k=m[np.where(closefix)[0]] 
    if k.size>0:
        statusMobile[k]=False
        grilleFixe[x[m],y[m]]=True
        nFixe+=len(k)

plt.imshow(grilleFixe)
plt.xlabel(' x')
plt.ylabel(' y')
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show
```

Comment: Please provide the rest of the inputs to turn this into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (what are `x`, `y`, `M`, `N`, `nIterMax` etc...). What precisely are you expecting to happen? All of the plotting happens outside of the `while` loop, so there is no way that you would see your points "move randomly".

Comment: explained the problem in detail, hope it makes sense now

Comment: Editing the title of your question so that it is an actual question will give you a better chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I am fairly new to this website

Comment: Could you post a link to this practice? I can't understand what algorithm you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that

```
grilleFixe[x[m],y[m]]=True
```

should read

```
grilleFixe[x[k],y[k]]=True
```

since `m` contains the set of all currently-mobile points, whereas `k` contains the indices of only those points that are touching other non-mobile points.

With that change, and your original parameters, I get fractals that look like this:

[image]